# How to take and verify hashed password from db

Tags: php, hash

In my **register.php** i use this code to make hashed password:

```
$user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];
$hash = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And i want to verify password hash in db but i dont know how to use password_verify correctly. Here is my login.php script to login

**login.php**

```
<?php
include('Global/global.inc.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])!='') {
header("Location: index.php");
}
include('Global/view/view.login.php');
//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_name']));
$user_pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, htmlspecialchars($_POST['user_pass']));
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `" . USERS_TABLE . "` WHERE user_name = '$user_name' AND user_pass = '$user_pass'");

if (empty($user_name) || empty($user_pass)) {
    echo "empty fields";
}
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_avatar'] = $row['user_avatar'];
        $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $row['user_mail'];

        header("Location: index.php");

    }
else {

    echo 'Invalid Username or Password!<br />';
}
}
```

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])!='') {` this will give you a false result. A boolean true/false can't ever be equal to an empty string, so that if-block will always return true.

Comment: RTM for `password_verify()` --> http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php and you will find a working example. *Hint:* `if (password_verify($unHashedPassword, $hashedPasswordFromDatabase))`

Comment: so how i must edit my code if not isset ? And i want to take hashed pass from db but i cant. Can make a corrections on my code ?

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['user_name'])!='') {` should just be `if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {`, and you can add `if (password_verify($user_pass, $row['password']))` after `if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` and put all the sessions in that. But you also need to remove `AND user_pass = '$user_pass'` from your query.

Comment: Its not possible to verify the password directly in the SQL statement because of salting. Instead read the stored hash from the database (searching only by user name as Qirel already pointed out) and check it with the `password_verify()` function.

Comment: its work yet :)
just `$hashed = $row['hash'];
if (password_verify($user_pass, $hashed)) {}`

Answer (score 0):

from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

`isset()` returns `bool true or false` you should only have

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

use `password_verify();`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

example

```
<?php
$hash = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Comment: I want to take hash from datebase and verify hash. If hash from my login = hash from datebase login succes ... how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

i edited your code and added some comments to make it clear hope it helps

```
if( isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) {
header("Location: index.php");
}

include('Global/view/view.login.php');
//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['user_name'])));
$user_pass = trim($_POST['password']); // trim deletes spaces from left and right password doesn't need sanitization 
//check fields
if (empty($user_pass) || empty ($user_name) ) {
    echo "empty fields";
}
 elseif ($result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql)){
     // check username if it exists procceds to password checking
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$hashedpassword = $row["password"];

//check password if username exists
if (password_verify($password, $hashedpassword))
    {

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_avatar'] = $row['user_avatar'];
        $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $row['user_mail'];
        header("Location: index.php");

    }

    } else {
    echo 'Invalid Username or Password!<br />';  
    } } else {
        echo 'Invalid Username or Password!<br />';
}
}
```

Comment: thank you but in your code we no have a query :)

Comment: elseif ($result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql))

Comment: where you define $sql as query ? maybe i must replace $sql with select from ..... ?

Comment: your code doesn't work ...

Comment: im sorry. i deleted my users table yesterday and now i try to login :D sorry about this. Thank you all for help. THANK YOU !!!

Comment: you are welcome <3 choose my answer as the one which answered your question i'll be thankful

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the login password with the DB hashed password, then convert the login password to hash and compare them both. That is:

> ```
> $user_pass = password_hash($user_pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
> ```

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `" . USERS_TABLE . "` WHERE user_name = '$user_name' AND user_pass = '$user_pass'");

if (empty($user_name) || empty($user_pass)) {
    echo "empty fields";
}
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
        $_SESSION['user_avatar'] = $row['user_avatar'];
        $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $row['user_mail'];

        header("Location: index.php");

    }
else {

    echo 'Invalid Username or Password!<br />';
}
}
```

Comment: This won't work because of the random salt, one cannot check the password in SQL.